# update record if exist else create new record rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title,placeholder: 'title' %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :gen_id,value: 55 %> #55 is just for testing
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

This is my controller

```
  def create
      @post = Post.find_by_id params[:gen_id]
      if @post
        @post.update(post_params)
        else
          @post = Post.new
            if @post.save!
              flash[:success] = 'Post added successfully'
              redirect_to action: :new
            else
              flash[:error] = 'Post cannot add. Please try again after some time'
               redirect_to action: :new
            end
       end
   end
```

The above code is just creating new record everytime

Comment: Are you using strong params in rails 3?

Comment: @acts_as_geek A am using rails 4

Comment: There is a `find_or_create_by(...)` method by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gen_id` is part of Post form. But you're looking for it at top level. You need to do this:

```
@post = Post.find_by_id params[:post][:gen_id]
```

or

```
@post = Post.where(id: params[:post][:gen_id]).first
```

Comment: Yea i changed it. it enters this loop `if @post` but i couldn't not find any updates in my table. i tried with `update_attributes` too. Any other change should be there?